# Why Tera Term's console only show 24 lines with Raspberry Pi?

Tags: console, raspberry-pi

I use Tera Term's console connect to Raspberry Pi 3 but the visible lines only 24.

Here is the environment variable
root@raspberrypi:~# export
...
declare -x LINES="24"
...

For expanding the visible lines, I remove the code "shopt -s checkwinsize" in the file "/etc/bash.bashrc" and I add code "export LINES=50" in the file "~/.bashrc".
Unfortunately, after the device reboot, the visible lines still is 24.
How to expand the visible lines?

Answer (score 0):

It's my fault.
Just only to modify the .vimrc and add the line setting as below.
set lines=50

Now I can use vim to edit file with 50 visible lines.